# Firefox add-on to record all web browsing

Tags: web, firefox, browser, browser-addons

I am looking for an add-on for Firefox that would record all my browsing online and create an index, perhaps only the text of the main body of the page, so that I can later go through everything I've seen and find stuff again. Something like what [greplin](http://www.greplin.com) does with social networks and services but for my entire browsing. I don't know if that's even possible and if it would deteriorate the performance so much it can't be made. Do you know if something like that exists? Do you think it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

May be you want something like flipora.

http://www.flipora.com

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/infoaxe-web-history-search-and/?src=search

However it doesn't have any good reviews ..

Comment: Yes, I found that and tried to sign up but the form didn't work and they didn't reply to my email. Thanks anyway!